# WiFi adapter detects all Wifi Hotspots except WPA - Entreprise ones

Tags: raspbian, wifi, networking

I am using a TP-Link TL-WN725N USB Wifi adapter with my raspberry Pi 2.
The adapter works well but as I am working in an organization, the Wireless Network I must use is a WPA2-Entreprise.

My Wifi Adapter detects all the Wifi Networs except those WPA2-Entreprise ...
I tried with wpa_gui, network manager, and also `iwlist wlan0 scan`, but these networks are never listed.

Is there any setting I must use ?

EDIT : With all my other computers, these networks are shown by `wpa_gui`.

Comment: The Pi has been known to have problems with WPA2-Enterprise networks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scan or connect to the WPA-E you need to tweak your hostapd conf then you can able to connect.

Try : `system-ca-cert=true`

from the configuration file found in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

For more help in configuring the WPA-E check this [documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA2_Enterprise).

The gap between WPA2-Personal and WPA2-Enterprise is rather large. WPA2-Enterprise is the strongest wireless security, but it is complex to administer because it requires a public key infrastructure (PKI) with server and client certificates, and a certificate authority.